# ProgrammingError at /api/contacts/

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I get the following error in my app:

[image: error]

I've have this model:

```
from django.db import models
from apps.account.models import Account
from .category import Category


class Contact(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    number_phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.OneToOneField(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        Account,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='contacts')

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

this view:

```
class ContactViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsAdminContact)

#    def get_permissions(self):
#        if self.request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
#            return (permissions.AllowAny(),)
#        return (permissions.IsAuthenticated(), IsAdmin(),)
```

The error begin when I define the following permissions for my api:

```
class IsAdminContact(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user.role == "admin":
            return request.user.role == "admin"
        return False

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, contact):
        if request.user.role == "admin":
            return request.user.role == "admin"
        return False
```

All was right, but when I define the permissions for my api contacts, boom!! this error... I dont know which is the problem, I tried all, but neither result... What is the problem?

Comment: It is probably because you have not migrated your models.

Comment: I tried those... But the error begin when I define the permissions for Contact

Comment: `python manage.py makemigrations` creates anything?

Comment: `(env) cuetodev@cuetodev-thinkpad-x131e:~/code/p-246/order_manager$ python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
`

Comment: No create nothing

Comment: then run `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Already, I 've do it... And don't work

Comment: Work in local, but not work in the heroku...